# Ограничение значений regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript, replace

Как можно ограничить значение regex?
Пользователь вводит №011, там где 011 - номер картинки. Это значение не может быть меньше  001 и больше 649. Как можно это реализовать?
То есть, например, нужно заменить тот же №011 на картинку под номером 011 :)

Comment: Согласен с @knes, здесь регулярное выражение не уместно, потому что если картинок станет больше, то придется заменять в коде регулярное выражение, либо генерировать его динамически на основе верхней границы диапазона каждый раз при обращении к скрипту.  
В данном случае лучше сравнивать числовые значения.

Comment: ну да, а регексом(или интвалом) вытаскивать всё число целиком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача не для регекса.
Но если очень хочется, то что-то типа

```
//648
64[0-8]|6[0-3][0-9]|[0-5]?[0-9][0-9]?
```

64[0-8] - если первые две цифры 64, то последняя максимум 8
6[0-3][0-9] - если первая шетсерка, а вторая - до тройки, то третья максимум - 9(09,19,29,39)
[0-5]?[0-9][0-9]? - все остальные числа с ведущими нулями и без.